# Google Apps Script - Creating and Saving Filters for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I feel like a bit of a chump, but I cannot work this out...

I have been given the job of producing a new master analysis sheet each month from a supplied XML file that combines with various columns of our (multiple) sheets.  No problems, so far.  I have got all of that working the way I want. :-)

My issue is that we also have about 6-8 filters saved with a specific sheet that allow our auditors to focus on specific areas (and as you can understand, our auditors want these to work EXACTLY as they specify).

I have tried using *createFilter()* but there doesn't appear any way to save multiple filters to that sheet (maybe I am missing something).  No joy! :-(

I have tried recording a macro which I could then run to create the filters.  No joy here either :-(

Do I have to tell these pesky auditors to create there own filters each month (they do know how, but it's beneath them), or is there a way I can script them up and get them off my back?

Unfortunately (as much as I would like to) I cannot share our sheets or scripts as we have significant IP embedded there.

I would really appreciate some guidance as to how you might approach this (if it is possible).

Kind regards

Ian

Comment: Are you talking about 'Create new filter view', so everybody can make their own, or the actual filter which applies to everyone?

Comment: why so complicated ? create a custom menu with all Menu's that act like your filters, wouldn't it be much easier? like e.g. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're indeed talking about the 'Create new filter view', I suggest making an template sheet. So instead of creating a new sheet every month, make one template spreadsheet and add all the filter views your auditors desire. Then copy that spreadsheet, and paste the new data in it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  After I slept on the issue I worked out the same solution and it works well.  (Great minds think alike!!)  Took a little bit of adjustment to get the scripts integrated but now it's going well.  Only frustration is the time limit on the scripts. I understand why Google did it, but it's way to short for me.  I have had to break it into about 10 pieces. Thanks again.  All the best.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to create a filter using Apps Script and the `createFilter()` is this one:

```
function setFilters() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeFilter = ss.getRange("INPUT_YOUR_RANGE_HERE");
  var filter = rangeFilter1.createFilter();
  var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();
  filterCriteria.ADD_YOUR_CRITERIA_HERE;
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition, filterCriteria.build());
}
```

As you can see, you must use `build()` in order to build the criteria for the filter you have created.

You can also use the Sheets advanced services and create the filters using the Sheets API, something similar to this:

```
  var filterSettings = {
  //YOUR FILTER SETTINGS
  };
  var request = [{
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  }];
```

And as for calling the Sheets service and applying the above filter, you can use this:

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': request}, SPREADSHEET_ID);
```

#### Reference

- [Range Class Apps Script createFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createfilter);
- [Filter Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter);
- [Apps Script Google Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

Comment: Great suggestion.  I will play with this option as well.  Thanks.